# Redis-py elementary operations huge delay

Tags: python, linux, sockets, redis, ipv6

I have noticed the slow work of my system depends on getting celery async task result on production system. During debug I founded a huge latency of redis-py elementary operations.

- Linux 3.16.0-36-generic Ubuntu 14.04
- Python 2.7.6
- redis-py 2.10.3
- Redis 2.8.19

---

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis()
r.set('foo', 'bar')  # takes about 2 minutes
r.set('bar', 'foo')  # runs 'instantly'
```

I'm sure it's not redis or connection problems (redis runs locally)

```
redis-benchmark -t set -n 10000 q
===== q ======
  10000 requests completed in 0.17 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

99.01% <= 1 milliseconds
99.11% <= 2 milliseconds
99.51% <= 15 milliseconds
100.00% <= 15 milliseconds
57471.27 requests per second
```

Then I tried profile it and got next cProfile output:

> ```
>    23    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:112(_read_from_socket)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:156(readline)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:175(purge)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:192(__init__)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:203(on_connect)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:223(read_response)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:385(__init__)
>     1    0.000    0.000  127.266  127.266 connection.py:428(connect)
>     1    0.000    0.000  127.266  127.266 connection.py:451(_connect)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:501(on_connect)
>     1    0.000    0.000  127.266  127.266 connection.py:529(send_packed_command)
>     1    0.000    0.000  127.266  127.266 connection.py:554(send_command)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:566(read_response)
>     3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:577(encode)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:593(pack_command)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:68(__init__)
>     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:858(_checkpid)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:868(get_connection)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:878(make_connection)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:885(release)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:99(__init__)
>     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 socket.py:185(__init__)
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 socket.py:192(close)
>     8    0.000    0.000  127.264   15.908 socket.py:223(meth)
>     1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 {_socket.getaddrinfo}
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {cStringIO.StringIO}
>    20    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {getattr}
>    11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
>    13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
>     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
>     2  127.264   63.632  127.264   63.632 {method 'connect' of '_socket.socket' objects}
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
>     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'endswith' of 'str' objects}
>     4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}
>     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'readline' of 'cStringIO.StringO' objects}
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'recv' of '_socket.socket' objects}
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'remove' of 'set' objects}
>     4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'seek' of 'cStringIO.StringO' objects}
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'sendall' of '_socket.socket' objects}
>     2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'setsockopt' of '_socket.socket' objects}
>     3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'settimeout' of '_socket.socket' objects}
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'truncate' of 'cStringIO.StringO' objects}
>     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'write' of 'cStringIO.StringO' objects}
>     3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.getpid}
>    18    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {setattr}
> ```

Why redis-py opening connection for so long time?

UPD:

With passed socket_connect_timeout connection opening duration ~ timeout. No exceptions were raised, `r.set('foo', 'bar')` returned True.

UPD:

```
>>> socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 6379)
[(10, 1, 6, '', ('::1', 6379, 0, 0)), (10, 2, 17, '', ('::1', 6379, 0, 0)), (10, 3, 0, '', ('::1', 6379, 0, 0)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('127.0.0.1', 6379)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('127.0.0.1', 6379)), (2, 3, 0, '', ('127.0.0.1', 6379))]

>>> sock_info = socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 6379)
>>> sock = socket.socket(*sock_info[0][:3])
>>> sock.connect(('localhost', 6379))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
  return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
>>> sock = socket.socket(*sock_info[1][:3])
>>> sock.connect(('localhost', 6379))  # success
```

Comment: Do you have the same benchmark using `redis.StrictRedis` instead of `redis.Redis` ?

Comment: @Orelus Yes I do.
127.225   63.613  127.225   63.613 {method 'connect' of '_socket.socket' objects}